# Unable to call web api PUT method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("{id}")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
    public async Task<ComplaintVM> Put(int id,int? employeeId)
    {
        var obj = _resolver.GetService<Complaint>();
        obj.FranchiseId = 1;
        obj.Id = id;
        await obj.GetDetailAsyc();
        obj.EmployeeId = employeeId;
        await obj.AllocateAndManageCallAsyc();
        return obj.EntityToVM();
    }
```

This is put method with [System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/app/complaint")]

so when i call my method with a PUT request i get the following error "message: "The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'.".

but when i make the same call when the method does not have int? employeeId parameter. The call happens fine.

I am passing the employeeId  as a json formatted request. I am using fiddler to test the code

Comment: can you please show us your call url (fiddler payload), your other controller actions etc.? it looks like the route matching is ending up on some otheraction which doesn't support PUT..

Comment: Have you tried putting the [FromBody] attribute on the employeeid parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with  `Put(int id,int? employeeId)` is the variable `int? employeeId`, since it was not part of the URL the model binder was not able to bind the attribute and hence was not able call the method with 2 parameters.

Using the `[FormBody]` did not work, the value returned was null, this is because the input was in form of a json.

The issue was solved by using a parameter of type `Employee` which had a property of `EmployeeId` so the value was mapped to the `EmployeeId` of the employee object, the method signature is `Put(int id,Employee employee)`,

if there is no model `class` to bind, a parameter of type `JObject` can used as a input parameter and later the value can be extracted from JObject.